# Understanding Execution Environment of a Process

Tags: c, process, exec, strace

How do I know the difference in the 'execution env' of a process in two different contexts?

To articulate the question properly, I have plan9port installed in `/opt/plan9/` and when I run the fortune program from `/opt/plan9/bin/fortune` it works fine. (reads the list of fortunes from `/opt/plan9/lib/fortune` and `/opt/plan9/lib/fortune.index` ). When I call it from inside of a c code (test.c) with

```
char* opts[] = {"fortune"};
execve("/opt/plan9/bin/fortune", opts, NULL);
```

It doesn't read the fortune list. I used strace to see what is the difference when I call these two binaries.

`strace -f -eopen ./test`

```
open("/usr/local/plan9/lib/fortunes", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
Misfortune!
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Gives out the default message "Misfortune".

`strace -f -eopen fortune`

```
open("/opt/plan9/lib/fortunes", O_RDONLY) = 3
Snob intellectual bachelors can't have fun in San Antonio.  -Ted Nelson
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

which works perfectly fine.

How do I change ./test read fortunes file. It must have something to do with the exec environment, from where the binary reads the libraries from.

Comment: While this doesn't appear to be causing your problem, you are not calling `execve()` correctly, as the array passed in the second argument (`opts`) must end in `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `execve()`, you are explicitly setting up a `NULL` environment. So the `fortune` program is probably depending on some environment variable to find `/opt/plan9/...`. Type `env` at a shell prompt to find out which environment variables are set.

Comment: relevant env variable is PLAN9 which is set as /opt/plan9. Should I pass it while calling execve()?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Don't forget to terminate your array of environment variables with a `NULL` entry.

Comment: Ok one more query. When I spawn zsh it calls fortune binary, and failing to read the correct /opt/plan9/lib/fortunes file it outputs Misfortune everytime. How do I make zsh work like test.c? What environment var do I have to set? any idea?

Comment: I'm not familiar with zsh specifically. Some shells require that you `export` environment variables so that other programs can see them.